# How return null from method

Tags: c#, nullable

I am java programmer, I am new at C# and I realy do not understand why Nullable type is needed. Can any one explain me?
 For example I have code:

```
 XmlReader xr=...
 string propertyValue=xr.GetAttribute("SomeProperty");
 if(propertyValue!=null) {
 //some code here
}
```

The propertyValue type is 'string' not 'string?' but 'GetAttribute' can return null.
 So, in fact, I should for each variable check if its value is null or not, so why nullable type '*?' is needed in general.
 How its can be useful?

And the second question:
How write my own method with return type 'string' and return null value from it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx

Comment: The key conceptual problem in this question is simply: picking `string` as the example... since `string` is not a struct, it doesn't fit. If you make the example `int`, it may become more self-explanatory

Answer (score 1):

You can have return type as `string` and return `null`, since **string is a reference type**, it can hold `null` as well.

```
public string SomeMethod()
{
    return null;
}
```

> The propertyValue type is 'string' not 'string?'

Data type with `?` are [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) data types which only works with value types, since string is a reference type you can't have `string?`. `?` is only syntactic sugar.

> In C# and Visual Basic, you mark a value type as nullable by using the
>   ? notation after the value type.

You may also see: [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx) type is used for [`struct`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). These are somewhat similar to Java's primitives (e.g. they can't be null), but are much more powerful and flexible (e.g. users can create their own `struct` types and you can call methods like `ToString()` on them).

When you want a nullable `struct` ("value type"), use `Nullable<T>` (or the identical `T?`). `class`es ("reference type") are always nullable, just like in Java.

E.g.

```
//non-nullable int
int MyMethod1()
{
    return 0;
}

//nullable int
int? MyMethod2()
{
    return null;
}

//nullable string (there's no such thing as a non-nullable string)
string MyMethod3()
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to last question:

Long way:

```
private string MethodReturnsString()
{
   string str1 = "this is a string";
   return str1;
}
```

Short way:

```
private string MethodReturnsString()
{
   return "this is a string";
}
```

str1 filled with: `"this is a string"`, will be returned to the method which calls it.

Call this method as follow:

```
string returnedString;
returnedString = MethodReturnsString();
```

`returnedString` will be filled with `"this is a string"` from `MethodReturnsString();`